# erlang file from post param

Tags: file, file-io, erlang, chicagoboss

I have a problem:
I need to read file from post param in ChicagoBoss. I'm trying:

```
upload_file('POST', []) ->
    File = Req:post_param("file"),
    {ok,Data} = file:read_file(File),
```

And have an error:

```
{{badmatch,{error,enoent}}
```

When I'm trying to check the file like:

```
case filelib:is_file(File) of
        true -> {output, "ok"};
        false -> {output, "error"}
end.
```

I have `error` output.
I'm trying to upload file with Postman. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

What's inside `Req:post_param("file")` ?

You assume it's a path to a file: have you checked the value of `File` ?

Anyway, it's `Req:post_files/0` you are probably looking for:

```
[{_, _FileName, TempLocation, _Size}|_] = Req:post_files(),
{ok,Data} = file:read_file(TempLocation),
```

It's also probably a Bad Idea to leave the file at it's temperory location, you'd better find a more suitable place to store them.

Comment: answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738391/how-to-read-from-post-param/21000758#21000758

Answer (score 0):

`enoent` is the posix error code for "directory not found."

http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#del_dir-1

Also, your code allows people to read arbitrary files from disk.  That will eventually lead to a server attack.